# Find exhaustive list of restaurants around a location within a specified radius in android

Tags: android-location

I am working on an Android App. I want to get list of all restaurant around me within a specified radius(let say 5 miles). I tried using Google places API and it works, however it limits the number results returned to 20, what if there are more than 20 restaurant in that radius around me. How do I get an exhaustive list of all the restaurants? What is the best way to do this? Is there something other than Google Places API that I can use? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it server side you can use this guy's class :

http://andrenosalsky.com/blog/2011/google-places-api-php-class/

and you have to get an api key as it is explaned here :

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/places/

then you can send data in JSON format to your Android